# Dagger Hilt :- kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property homeView has not been initialized in l̥Dagger Hilt

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

this is my viewmodel class

```
class HomeFeedViewModel( val applicationContext: Context, val repo: repository) : ViewModel() {

lateinit private var homeView: HomeView     }
```

this is my homeview interface:-

```
interface HomeView {
fun OnSuccessLoadFeed(
        showPostBean: ArrayList<Data_model>,
        lastPage: String,
        currentPage: String
)
fun onSuccessNoContent(msg: String)
fun onSuccessLocation(userBean: Data_model)
fun onSuccessLikePost(likePostBean: Data_model)
}
```

this is my module class for store object of interface :-

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
abstract class InterfaceModule {

@ExperimentalPagingApi
@Binds
abstract fun getHomeView(fragHome: Frag_home): HomeView

@ExperimentalPagingApi
@Binds
abstract fun getDetailPostview(detailPost: Detail_post): DetailPostview

}
```

all set-up of dagger-hilt is done and  @HiltAndroidApp annotation also provided in application class

Comment: Have you added `@AndroidEntryPoint` for your Frag_home and HomeView?

Comment: Homeview is interface cause of that i cant pass @androidentrypoint to the interface

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here:

First: You cannot field inject something into your viewmodel. Only constructor injection is allowed. For this, you have to modify your viewmodel the following:

```
@HiltViewModel
class HomeFeedViewModel(
      @ApplicatonContext private val applicationContext: Context, 
      private val repo: repository
) : ViewModel()
```

Second: Your HomeView cannot be injected inside your viewmodel, because it depends on a `Frag_Home` as its "base class". If you want to inject `HomeView` inside your viewmodel, you have to change your dependency the following:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object Module {

@ExperimentalPagingApi
@Binds
// here you need some Implementation of HomeView to provide it to your singleton graph
fun getHomeView(homeViewImpl: HomeViewImpl): HomeView

}
```